# Android license status unknown.Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Cuando hago flutter doctor aparece el error con el sdk

[image: Este error aparece]

La ruta de mi SDK de android studio es C:\Androidstudio\sdkAndroid

Esta correctamente como lo tengo en el Manager de Android Studio, pero aun asi flutter no lo reconoce.

Si ejecuto un `flutter doctor -v` aparece esto:

[image: Esto aparece,la ruta es la misma de mi SDK de Android Studio]

Adjunto imagenes del SDK y Manager en Android studio

Es el SDK Platforms:
[image: Es el SDK Platforms]

SDK tools:
[image: SDK tools]

Mi directorio de SDK:
[image: Mi directorio de SDK]

Intenté con el comando:

```
flutter config --android-sdk C:\Androidstudio\sdkAndroid
```

Answer (score -1):

debes aceptar las licencias Android por un lado, googlea porque no estoy seguro como es en windows. seguramente es por linea de comando "sdkmanager --licenses" en la carpeta donde se ubique Android SDK Tools.
Y por otro debes instalar el plugin de flutter y el de dart en  Android Studio, en las ultimas capturas que pusiste, a la izquierda donde dice plugins.
espero te sirva